# Evaluation of complex integral

Tags: complex-integration

$$\int_{\text{c}}\frac{\sin \pi z^2 + \cos \pi z^2}{(z+1)(z+2)}$$

Where $\text{C}$ is the circle $|z| =3$

I'm a little confused about how to do this. Should this be done the normal way ? How do I use the concept of what C is and the concepts of complex analysis ?

Comment: Before looking at the answer below I feel obliged to ask if that squared is on the trig function or their argument

Comment: @Triatticus Argument

Comment: Oh okay I see now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use partial fraction expansion to write

$$\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)}=\frac{1}{z+1}-\frac{1}{z+2}$$

Then, applying [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem), we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{\sin(\pi z^2)+\cos(\pi z^2)}{(z+1)(z+2)}\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{\sin(\pi z^2)+\cos(\pi z^2)}{z+1}\,dz-\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{\sin(\pi z^2)+\cos(\pi z^2)}{z+2}\,dz\\\\
&=2\pi i\left(\sin(\pi)+\cos(\pi)-\sin(4\pi)-\cos(4\pi)\right)\\\\
& =-4\pi i
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: I just have a doubt. Doesn't Cauchy have another theorem which says that the integral around any closed path is zero ?

Comment: @user230452 You are correct.  [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) states precisely that.  [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) is the one used here.

Comment: If you used, Cauchy's theorem instead, the integral would be zero ?

Comment: Cauchy's Integral Theorem does not apply since the integrand is not analytic in the region $|z|\le 3$